# Writing html tags inside html

Tags: html, prism.js

I am writing a blog where I need to explain HTML tags. However, I am using HTML to make the blog and need away to get html written inside html. I am using prism.js to give the html syntax highlighting

```
<pre class="language-html"> <script src="node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script</pre>
```

Comment: Use the <code> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Replace < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`

### Example:

```html
<h1>This is a normal html element!</h1>

&lt;h1&gt;This is not!&lt;/h1&gt;
```